# Unable to handle error: `middleware is not a function' in redux-promise-middleware?

Tags: react-native, redux-promise-middleware

I am trying to use redux-promise-middleware in my app, but when I am trying to run my app error comes with an error message: 'middleware is not a function or middleware is null'.

**I tried to use middleware without a function as suggested in redux async docs, but still error is coming.**

configureStore.js

---

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux'
import app from './reducers/index';
import PromiseMiddleware from 'redux-promise-middleware';

const configureStore = () => {
    let middleware = applyMiddleware(PromiseMiddleware());
    let store = createStore(app, middleware);
    return store
};

export default configureStore;
```

index.js

---

```
import React from 'react'
import { AppRegistry } from 'react-native';
import App from './App';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import configureStore from './configureStore'

const store = configureStore();

const ReduxMiddleware = () => {
    <Provider store={store}>
        <App />
    </Provider>
}

AppRegistry.registerComponent('ReduxMiddleware', () => ReduxMiddleware);
```

**Please anybody, suggest to me that why I am facing this error.
I am new to redux.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import promiseMiddleware from 'redux-promise-middleware';

composeStoreWithMiddleware = applyMiddleware(
   promiseMiddleware,
)(createStore);
```

And not : PromiseMiddleware()

(not uppercase and w/o ()   )